# how to create a gradle test suite without using built-in frameworks

Tags: gradle

Lets say I created a new and unique Java test framework, or I am retro-fitting a legacy project where the tests are just `main(String[] args)`-entrypoint classes and I would like to run those with `gradle test` and have gradle exit with 0 if none of the tests fail/nothing throws.

"without built-in frameworks" - meaning, without [useJUnit()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:useJUnit()), [useJUnitPlatform()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:useJUnitPlatform()) et al.